# PlotStyle for GridLines

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
Plot[x^2,{x, 0, 5},GridLines->{{3,4}},PlotRange->{5,30},PlotStyle->{Black,Dotted,Thickness[0.003]}]
```

[image]

How to make these two vertical lines in style `{Black,Dotted,Thickness[0.003]}`? Or maybe there is some other way (without `GridLines`) to plot these vertical lines, but not using `ContourPlot`.

Comment: Could use `GridLinesStyle -> {{Black, Dotted, Thickness[0.003]}, None}`

Comment: It works great, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
styles = Directive[Black, Dotted, Thickness[0.003], Opacity[1]];
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}, GridLines -> {{{3, styles}, {4, styles}}}, 
 PlotRange -> {5, 30}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dotted, Thickness[0.003]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Nonetheless these vertical lines are gray not black for me.

Comment: @misha.physics This is the feature of opacity instead of gray,just add `Opacity[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way (without `GridLines`) is use `Epilog` or `Prolog`.  An advantage of this is grid lines can be added to the plot with the simplest `GridLines->Automatic` option without affecting the the vertical lines.  Here is an example that uses color, thickness and dashing to distinguish the function, the grid lines and the vertical lines.

```
vlines = {Black, Dotted, Thickness[0.005], 
   InfiniteLine[{#, 0}, {0, 1}] & /@ {3, 4}};

Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotRange -> {5, 30}, Prolog -> vlines]
```

[image]